# Docker on AWS - Environment Variables not inheriting from host to container

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, docker

I have a script (hosted on [GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScreamingJoypad/jmeter-armada/master/userdata.sh)) that does the following:

- Creates an EC2 instance on AWS
- Saves the local IP (private IP address) as an environment variable `$LOCALIP`
- Installs Docker (official repo)
- Updates the base instance (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)
- Pulls a custom image of mine
- Runs said image with the `-e LOCALIP` trying to pass the hosts environment variable to the container (I have also tried `-e LOCALIP=$LOCALIP`

However when I `docker exec` into the container on that instance and run `echo $LOCALIP` it displays nothing. Running `env` shows me that `LOCALIP` is there but nothing is against it

If I destroy the container and remake using the exact same line from the original script (with `-e LOCALIP=$LOCALIP`) it works - I need this process automating however and some  additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Essentially `sudo docker run -dit -e LOCALIP -p 1099:1099 -p 50000:50000 screamingjoypad/armada-server /bin/bash` is not sharing the hosts `LOCALIP` variable.

UPDATE

Trying the suggestions from below I added the following line to my script
`source /etc/bash.bashrc` but this still does not work. I'm still getting a blank when trying the `echo $LOCALIP` in the container...

[image]

Comment: it should be -e LOCALIP=$LOCALIP, can you run with `sudo -E`, as the sudo will run as root user and might not have access to environment variables, -E would pass the users env variables to the root.

Comment: Sadly I already tried this `-e LOCALIP=$LOCALIP` and it didn't work however is there a difference with it being a capitol E?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of this line of your shell script:

```
echo "export LOCALIP=$(hostname -i)" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

After this command is executed, the `export` instruction does not take effect yet. It will take effect after your next login.

To make the `LOCALIP` environment variable take effect immediately, add this line after the `echo "export ...` command:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work? I think I'm using it in the right context (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScreamingJoypad/jmeter-armada/master/userdata.sh)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've solved it. I'm now using the AWS metadata to harvest the private IP address using the following addition to the script:

`sudo docker run -dit -e LOCALIP=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4) -p 1099:1099 -p 50000:50000 screamingjoypad/armada-server /bin/bash`